# Loop through Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm working with two workbooks. In the first I search for the value in the cell to the right of "Charge Number". Take that value and search the second workbooks pivot table for the matching row, copy it and go back to first work book and paste the data. This works great once. But I'm unable to get a loop to look for the next instance of "Charge Number" and repeat the process. The loop I have in the code isn't right because it finds the first value fine but then searches every next row for the same Charge Number.

```
Sub FindChargeNo()

    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim ChgNum As String
    Dim SrchRng2 As String
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Dim FstWB As Workbook
    Dim SecWB As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range

    Set FstWB = Workbooks("First.xlsm")
    Set SecWB = Workbooks("Second_test.xlsx")
    Set ws1 = FstWB.Worksheets("New Development")
    Set ws = SecWB.Worksheets("Aug 18 Report")
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables(1)

    lastRow = FstWB.Worksheets("New Development").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Set Loc = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="Charge Number")
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            ChgNum = Loc.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Debug.Print ChgNum
            Debug.Print SrchRng

            With pvt.PivotFields("Project WBS").PivotItems(ChgNum).LabelRange
                Set rng = ws.Range(.Resize(.Rows.Count, pvt.TableRange1.Columns.Count).Address)
                ws.Range(rng.Address).Copy
            End With

            SrchRng2 = Loc.Offset(0, 5).Address
            FstWB.Worksheets("New Development").Range(SrchRng2).PasteSpecial

        Set Loc = ws1.Cells.FindNext(Loc)
        Loop While Loc.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need FindNext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext to continue searching beyond first match.

Comment: Yup, just before your `Next`, you need `Set Loc = ws1.Cells.FindNext`